# How much does a hat of disguise cost exactly?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, pricing

I can find two different prices for making a Hat of Disguise. Does it just cost half the material cost if all spells are accounted for or what?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. Thank you for your participation and have fun.

Answer (score 6):

The [*hat of disguise*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/hat-of-disguise) has a **price** of 1,800 gp. This is the amount that a vendor sells a *hat of disguise* for if one is for sale. If you already have a *hat of disguise* and sell it to a vendor, he typically pays you half this price.

The *hat of disguise* has a **cost** to create of 900 gp. This is how much a creator pays for raw materials to manufacture a *hat* on his own instead of just buying one. This cost usually includes the masterwork item that will become the magic item unless otherwise specified (as it is with, for example, magic armor, shields, and weapons).

In addition to the raw materials cost, however, a *hat*'s creator must meet the *hat*'s other creation prerequisites, like possessing the feat [Craft Wondrous Item](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-wondrous-item-item-creation---final) and the ability to create an effect like the spell [*disguise self*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/disguise-self) each day he's working on the *hat*. It usually takes a typical creator that meets all the prerequisites 2 days in a lab or shrine to make a *hat of disguise* and a successful [Spellcraft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/spellcraft) skill check (DC 5 + the item's caster level). You can read more about creating magic items—including, for example, how to avoid fulfilling *some* prerequisites and still create the magic item you want—in [Magic Item Creation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation).

---

***Note:*** Be careful not to confuse the typical hat of disguise *with the* greater hat of disguise *on the same page! The latter is a totally different item that creates a different effect (like the* [alter self](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/alter-self) *spell instead of the* disguise self *spell), therefore possessing a different cost, a different price, and different prerequisites.*

Comment: So this would be 900gp and all spells with a craft check at the end correct?

Comment: @Robbot78910  Sort of. Also necessary, for instance, is the right environment for creating the magic item. Note that even then, no matter the result of the Spellcraft skill check, the creator usually can't ignore the Craft Wondrous Item prerequisite nor ignore the raw materials cost nor create any faster. Best to read the section, though, and come back with specific questions. Also, [the site has already answered a bunch of questions on item creation.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder+crafting)